# C++ Window Scanner

Tags: c++

Need help with the loop. My Idea was scann for windows and when a window found check its procces Id so if the window was already found dont try to find it again. A piece from my code is like that:

```
if (Selection == 1)
{
    cout << endl << "================================= Scan Result =================================" << endl;
    cout << endl << "Scan Log:                                                        Times Found: " << TimesFound << endl;
    cout << "   - Scanning windows..." << endl;

    while(PressedKey != 27)
    {
        if (kbhit())
        {
            PressedKey = getch();
        }

        HWND WindowFound = FindWindow(0, "Untitled - Notepad");

        if (WindowFound != 0) 
        {
                            // My Idea was compare the procces Id of the found window
                            // to learn the found window was already found
            DWORD ProcessId;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(WindowFound, &ProcessId);

            if(ProcessId != OtherId)
            {
                TimesFound++;
                cout << "Window found ! Times found: " << TimesFound << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you guys can help me. Cheers

Edit: New Code

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumFunc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    wchar_t lpString[32];

    GetWindowText(hwnd, (LPSTR)lpString, _countof(lpString));

    if(wcscmp(lpString, L"Untitled - Notepad") == 0) 
    {
        *((int *)lParam)++;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

This part of *((int *)lParam)++; code not works. Error is: expression must be a modifiable lvalue @MikeKwan

Edit: Me with same question again @MikeKwan :)

```
    while(PressedKey != 27)
    {
        if (kbhit())
        {
            PressedKey = getch();
            printf("Times found: %d \n", TimesFound);
        }

        EnumWindows(EnumFunc, (LPARAM)&TimesFound);
    }
```

I use this code to detect window every time but It detects a window and it redetects the same window again and again so nothing is changed :/

Comment: What's your problem, what doesn't work?

Comment: The problem is that the `TimesFound` will not represent the number of windows with the matching caption name.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, `FindWindow` is not aware of your list of already seen windows so it will continue to return the same window (although this is implementation defined). Regardless, `FindWindow` does not have the capability to do what you are attempting (skip windows during its search).

If you want to enumerate all windows only once, you should use [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I wrote some example C code for `EnumWindows` that does what I am guessing you want to achieve. You will need to convert it to C++ but your usage of C++ is not particularly of the language at the moment anyway.

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumFunc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    /*
     * We don't care about getting the whole string,
     * just enough to do the comparison. GetWindowText
     * will truncate the string if we tell it to.
     */
    wchar_t lpString[32];

    GetWindowText(hwnd, lpString, _countof);

    if(wcscmp(lpString, L"Untitled - Notepad") == 0) {
        (*(int *)param)++;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int main(void)
{
    int numFound = 0;

    EnumWindows(EnumFunc, (LPARAM)&numFound);
    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

(Just wrote this in the answer window so there might be small errors).

Comment: `FindWindowEx` lets you resume the search, but it is open to the window destruction race condition. `EnumWindows` is safer, as you noted.

Comment: `LPARAM` is not defined as a pointer anymore (it's either __int64 or long according to the MSDN "Windows Data Types" article). This means another form of incrementing the variable is required (like using a global variable). Also, you're comparing the result of `GetWindowText` to something over 16 characters long, so it won't match, since your buffer was 16. There had to be something :p. Other than that, it works perfectly for me at least. Also, the only change to port it to C++ is to remove the `void` from `int main(void)`.

Comment: @chris: `LPARAM` is defined to `LONG_PTR` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx), which in turn is defined to `__int3264`, which is 32 bit on 32-bit platforms and 64-bit on 64-bit platforms. As you noted, I can't count though :) By converting to C++, I meant he might want to make it more OOP, etc.

Comment: Ah, that's always a good idea depending on what you're doing. `__int3264`, while it may be `long` and `__int64` in one, is still not a pointer as far as I know. I kind of skipped the `LONG_PTR` part and went straight to the `LONG_PTR` typedef.

Comment: Well `long` is guaranteed by the C standard to be at least 32 bits. And `__int64` is 64 bits. As long as the type is large enough to fit a pointer (it is), it's fine and this code will work. Unless you mean something else by 'is still not a pointer'? Passing a pointer to a `struct` or primitive type through `LPARAM` is quite common in  Win32. In fact, Windows messages exhibit this very usage! See an article from @RaymondChen: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/25/55850.aspx

Comment: Wow, Thanks all for answers specially Mike Kwan, I learned a lot thanks again :)

Comment: @MikeKwan I fixed a bit but I couldnt fix a part of it. The post is updated

Comment: I screwed up with the bracketing. The code is fixed now. You have another problem though, that you are mixing my code which is using Unicode strings with your own code which is using multi-byte strings. You should really be using Unicode with Win32 programming in this day and age. You shouldn't have to add any string casts if you have your configuration set up properly.

Comment: EnumWindows is iterating through all the windows once. You are calling it in a loop so I'm not really sure what you're expecting.

Comment: @MikeKwan In my program when I click 1 the scanner starts and detects the antivirus virus report window untill the user presses ESC key to quit. So I wanna learn how many times that the antivirus report window appeared while the scan is running.

Comment: What does this mean? That you expect the window to disappear and reappear? Does that mean it goes invisible then visible or is the window destroyed and recreated (this would change its handle)?

Comment: I expect when the antivirus window reappers while still the window scanner is active, I wanna detect it each time it appears.

Comment: For example: Scanner is active - Antivirus is window is popped up - Scanner grabs it and add TimesFound + 1 and writes it to console - Time has passed antivirus window closed - Antivirus window repopped - Scanner grabbed it again and added 1 to TimesFound again.

Comment: Okay you need to keep a list of all the detected window handles. Then when in the `EnumFunc`, only increment the counter if the new handle is not in the list.